# an alternative to hiding data in divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

All too often I find myself storing object data in hidden dom elements. I was curious if there was a way to attach this data to the dom node itself. When I try to create attributes 'on the fly', it doesn't seem to work. It would be much easier to access the property with this.something instead of accessing the html contained in a child. I feel like I should know how to do this, but I don't. Thanks.

Comment: As already mentioned, jQuery.data is probably what you are looking for. That said, look into the html5 specs and the `data-` attributes, which are pretty awesome, and something that you will see used already on many sites, since they don't break in non html5 browsers :)

Comment: Not sure why adding attributes 'on the fly' isn't working for you.  Have a look at this example to see how to make it work (http://www.webdevout.net/test?01o)

Comment: thanks nybbler, guess I hadn't tried it that way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There absolutely is! jQuery's [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

```
$('#someId').data('myData', someValue); // To store the data
$('#someId').data('myData'); // To retrieve it again
```

Any JavaScript variable can be stored as data - it's not limited to strings.

Note that this doesn't actually attach data to the DOM node as you say (which should be avoided). jQuery keeps its own cache of all the data you store and the DOM nodes you wanted to attach it to. So, it's not the same as `domNode.myData = someValue`.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the `data()` method will use the HTML5 `data-` attributes as a storage / retrieval mechanism.  It is possible to write your markup with data attributes that can be read by jQuery.  EG: `<div id="animal-1" data-animal="cat">Cat</div>` the value of the `data-animal` attribute can be retrieved like so: `alert($('#animal-1').data('animal')); //cat`

Comment: @Nathan, I probably should have mentioned that. Although the HTML attribute is only used for retrieval not storage, and only for the initial value.

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery.data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) is the preferred way of doing this.